# cannot build ORBIT2: fix apparently found but where is it?

Tags: linux, makefile, orbit

I cannot compile ORBIT2:

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/software/orbit2/ORBit2-2.14.19/linc2/src'
/bin/bash ../../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../../linc2/include -I../../linc2/include -pthread -I/usr/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/lib/glib-2.0/include   -Wall -Wunused -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -DG_DISABLE_DEPRECATED -D_GNU_SOURCE    -g -O2 -Werror-implicit-function-declaration  -MT linc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/linc.Tpo -c -o linc.lo linc.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../../linc2/include -I../../linc2/include -pthread -I/usr/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -Wall -Wunused -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -DG_DISABLE_DEPRECATED -D_GNU_SOURCE -g -O2 -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -MT linc.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/linc.Tpo -c linc.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/linc.o
linc.c: In function ‘link_init’:
linc.c:199:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘g_thread_supported’
linc.c:200:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘g_thread_init’
linc.c:204:2: warning: ‘g_type_init’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/glib-2.0/gobject/gtype.h:667)
linc.c:262:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘g_cond_new’
linc.c:262:18: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
linc.c:263:23: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
linc.c: In function ‘link_mutex_new’:
linc.c:324:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘g_mutex_new’
linc.c:324:3: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast
linc.c: In function ‘link_exec_set_io_thread’:
linc.c:463:3: error: implicit declaration of function ‘g_thread_create_full’
linc.c:464:4: error: ‘G_THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
linc.c:464:4: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
linc.c: In function ‘link_mainloop_handle_input’:
linc.c:94:7: warning: ignoring return value of ‘read’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
```

The bug has been reported and apparently fixed here, in october 2013:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=707456
But the fix does not appear to have been committed upstream (latest release 2010):
ftp://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/ORBit2/2.14
nor on the git repository (only 3 commits since early 2013):
https://git.gnome.org/browse/ORBit2/
But I cannot find the patch that fixes the issue.

The problem is also set as 'fixed' here:
https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/39138
but again, there is the patch?

I don't understand how those distributions work.  It's frustrating that a fix appears to have been found, but I cannot find it.

I don't understand the content of the orbit2-NMU.patch  in the debian issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from changes to the debian package the only change i can spot is removing "-DG_DISABLE_DEPRECATED" from CPPFLAGS in linc2/src/Makefile.am

Try it!